# ExifInterface - can't open '/storage/emulated/.../102214.jpg'"

Tags: android, bitmap, orientation, exif

I am trying to get orientation information from an image I took with the installed camera app on an Android phone.

When I call

```
 ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(fileUri.getPath().toString());
```

I am getting

```
 can't open '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraApp/IMG_20140801_102214.jpg'
```

I have set the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, might this be a problem with the KitKat version of Android?

Btw., fileUri is created using, among other stuff,

```
 File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`.

Comment: You might want to consider improving this answer with more context and an explanation of where and how to implement this.